# Blank page displaying instead of Page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I've tried searching for a solution to this issue but to no avail. I would appreciate any help in the matter.

I started a "tabs" default project, which worked as intended as a base. And added these few modifications, and end up with a blank screen.

in app.js:

```
    .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        views: {
          'login': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
            controller: 'LoginCtrl'
          }
        }
    })
```

below the initial tab definition. My otherwise is:

```
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
```

My view is located in templates/login.html:

```
    <ion-view view-title="login">
      <ion-content>
        <div class="bar bar-header bar-positive">
          <h1 class="title">Project :: Login</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="list">
          <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
            <span class="input-label">Email</span>
            <input type="text" placeholder="example@email.com">
          </label>
          <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
            <span class="input-label">Password</span>
            <input type="password" placeholder="********">
          </label>
          <button class="button button-block button-positive">
            Sign in
          </button>
        </div>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-view>
```

I also have an empty Controller definition in controllers.js:

```
    .controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope) {})
```

On application start, the routing successfully goes to localhost:/#/login, but displays a blank page.

I only get one console error when running **ionic serve**:

```
     ? (node:5592) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported.
     If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.
```

But I have removed this warning/error by downgrading to node@4.4.5. The blank page issue still persists. It displays a grey header and a blank body.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I think you forgot to put ng-controller="LoginCtrl" attribute in login.html

Comment: @JordanPlamondon his ctrl is stated in his routing.

Comment: Are you using any kind of JS compression? Like Gulp or Grunt to uglify your code?

Comment: Do you have any console errors? If so can you post them?

Comment: @Tim I don't have any console errors other than:  ? (node:5592) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you
are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version. It also works perfectly if I remove my new route.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. I had to update this in index.html:

```
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
```

To this:

```
    <ion-nav-view name="login"></ion-nav-view>
```

The application now loads my route. I discovered this when I looked into how the tabs.html was loading the data:

```
    <ion-tab title="Status" 
             icon-off="ion-ios-pulse" 
             icon-on="ion-ios-pulse-strong" 
             href="#/tab/dash">
      <ion-nav-view NAME="TAB-DASH"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
```